# Reference books on nuclear dimension of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Do there exist some reference books about nuclear dimension of $C^*$-algebras.

I saw some papers concerning the nuclear dimension of $C^*$-algebras and found it difficult to understand the proofs of some propositions.

Comment: The concept of nuclear dimension has not been around for that long, so I'd be surprised if there were any books written on the topic. It is quite an active research topic, especially in classification (for example the Toms-Winter conjecture relating finite nuclear dimension to strict comparison is still a big question as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 2):

The concept of nuclear dimension is still relatively young, so I doubt there are any books with a systematic treatment of it.  That said, I am aware of a soon to be published book by Karen Strung (see [here](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783030474645)) which has a short section detailing the basic properties of nuclear dimension.

Until that book comes out, I would recommend reading through the original paper of Winter and Zacharias (on the arxiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4914)).  Another option would be to first read about decomposition rank, a precursor to nuclear dimension, starting with the original paper (on the arxiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207164)).

Comment: Karen Strung has uploaded a draft of the book on her website, see here: https://strung.me/karen/CStarIntroDraft.pdf
I would be cautious reading through this though as it is only a draft. I have come across some little mistakes and I am unsure about the placement of some exercises, but that's just my opinion. Overall I think it is a very helpful text.